# How to add existing user to an existing group?

Tags: users, groups

I want to add the Apache user (`www-data`) to the `audio` group. I've read the man page for `useradd`, but I'm not having any luck. I'm running xubuntu 11.10. Here's what I'm doing:

```
$ sudo useradd -G audio www-data
useradd: user 'www-data' already exists
```

If I leave out the `-G` option, bash, prints the help info for `useradd`:

```
$ sudo useradd  audio www-data
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
Options: -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory...
```

It's not clear to me from the man page what options I should use to make this work.

Answer (score 1296, accepted):

The [`useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/useradd.8) command will try to add a new user. Since your user already exists this is not what you want.

Instead: To modify an existing user, like adding that user to a new group, use the [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/usermod.8) command.

Try this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
```

- **The `-a` (append) switch is essential**. Otherwise, the user will be removed from any groups, not in the list.
- The `-G` switch takes a (comma-separated) list of additional groups to assign the user to.

In general (for the GUI, or for already running processes, etc.), the user **will need to log out and log back in** to see their new group added. For the current shell session, you can use `newgrp`:

```
newgrp groupName
```

- [`newgrp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/newgrp.1) adds the group to the current shell session.

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G [group-name] [user-name]` : Just a quickie for those who only glance at the answer after reading the headline

Comment: What does the -a do? It seems to be depreciated / doesn't work with it but the command works with it removed. I can't seem to find reference in a few versions of man... but, I have seen it in so many examples - what does it do?

Comment: I think the preferred way now is `sudo adduser user group`.  It is simpler and cleaner syntax. See the response from @Bai.

Comment: @wilhil: `man usermod`: "**-a, --append** - Add the user to the supplementary group(s). Use only with the -G option.; **-G, --groups** GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]] *[...]* If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed, the user will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current supplementary group list."

Comment: Is there a way to get around the "logout and back in" part? Some type of update-groups command, maybe?

Comment: @con-f-use, if you can run `sudo login -f YOURUSERNAME`, it will start a new shell session. Use the `id` command to verify that the new session is in the correct set of groups. However, this isn't "global" - it doesn't apply to terminals that are already open. So, really, logging out is the best option, where possible

Comment: You can use the `newgrp [group-name]` command to add a new group to the user of the **current session** without logging out and in again. Only the current session will be affected though.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, thanks for the nice tip!  There are situations when logging out is not an option and your tip saved me some troubles!

Comment: @con-f-use: I think a `su - USERNAME` will directly activate a new shell with the new groups settings available. From the [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html): SYNOPSYS: su [options] [-] [user [argument...]]
DESCRIPTION su allows commands to be run with a substitute user and group ID. The `-` is a short form for the `login`parameter.

Comment: `newgrp` does not add the group to the current shell session. `newgrp` sets the user's **primary** group for the current session. Logging out and logging back in again updates the list of **secondary** groups - it does not modify the **primary** group at all, hence using newgrp is **not** an alternative to logging out and logging back in again. If you want an alternative to logging out and logging back in again, try `exec sg <groupName> newgrp` i.e. `exec sg audio newgrp`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76889494/3499840). HTH.

Answer (score 261):

Adding a user to a group:

```
sudo adduser user group
```

Removing a user from a group:

```
sudo deluser user group
```

Comment: not exactly what this question being asked for

Comment: @Tejendra's comment seems to presuppose that using useradd is desirable/mandatory to answer OP's question; Perhaps this answer is just missing words to indicate that adduser/deluser is a better alternative.

Comment: For me simpler interface is better, that's why I like this one.

Comment: this is debian/ubuntu specific?

Comment: This is _exactly_ the question being asked. @knocte, yes, I think it is Debian specific

Comment: @Auspex I can confirm that it does not work on Red Hat.

Answer (score 72):

After adding to a existing user:

```
usermod -a -G group user
```

You may **need to logout and login** to get the groups permissions from `/etc/group`.

Comment: FYI: I think the `id` command should indicate you were added to the group without needing to exit. `id myuser`

Comment: Logging out and back in was required for me on Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 34):

I normally use

```
sudo gpasswd -a myuser mygroup
```

Comment: usermod was not available on my system ubuntu 14.04.  This worked great!

Comment: This worked great on Debian Stretch too, where `usermod` was not installed.

Comment: Remember to log out and in again.

Answer (score 15):

I'm posting this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment. As @dpendolino's mentioned, for the effects of this command to persist:

`sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName`

...you need to logout/login again.

However, if you need a shortcut to start using your new group membership *immediately* (and you have the correct **sudo** privileges) I have found this work-around:

```
$ sudo su -
# su [userName]
$ groups
```

Explanation:

- `sudo su -` will give you a root shell
- `su [userName]` returns you to a shell with your user
- `groups` when run now will show the group you added with the `usermod -aG` command

In my case I was trying to add the 'docker' group to my user

Before:

```
$ groups
userName adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare wireshark lxd
```

After:

```
$ groups
userName adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare wireshark lxd docker
```

Comment: Another option to apply the group membership is `sudo login -f <username>`, as per Aaron McDaid's comment on another answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
```

will work just fine, but I had to **reboot** entirely, just log out and log in again did not do the job...

Comment: I found this too, and I wonder if it's because I'm running Wayland.

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu, since [logging in as `root` is not enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), users in the `sudo` group can elevate privileges for certain restricted commands. Any restricted command must be prepended with `sudo` to elevate privilege.

```
sudo usermod -a -G group user
```

will add the existing user **`user`** to a supplemental group named *`group`*. The user's primary group will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

To permanantely add a user to a group, run this command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G <groupname> <username>
```

Then log out and log in again (or reboot if necessary).

### Explanation:

The [`usermod` command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/usermod.8.html) will modify the [`/etc/group` file](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/group.5.html) to list the specified username in the line relevant to that group. If you run `grep <groupname> /etc/group`, you should see your username in the output.

In Linux, every process is assigned to a user and groups, and any child processes inherit the user and groups of the parent process. So, for this change to take effect and propogate, you need to log out and log in again (at which point `/etc/group` is read and used). On Wayland, I've found that a full reboot is necessary.

If you run the command `groups`, you can see if the current process has the expected groups or not.