# How to mount a VirtualBox shared folder at startup?

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu installed in Virtualbox. I want to mount my VirtualBox shared folder in Ubuntu automatically when I log in Ubuntu. I put the following line in my ~./bashrc and ~/.bash_profile:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf windows_share /media/windows_share
```

where windows_share is the name I created with Virtualbox. But everytime I start my Ubuntu, it asks me for passwd since it needs sudo. Is there anyway to automatically mount Windows share without entering password every time I log in?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

To always mount a Virtual Box "shared folder" on booting an Ubuntu guest we have two options. It is up to personal preference which option works best in our setting.

#### 1. Mount with fstab

To mount a shared folder using the `vboxsf` filesystem provided with [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox) we first need to make sure [prerequisites are met](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest). Then we may put the following line in our `etc/fstab` file:

```
<name_of_share>   /path/to/mountpoint   vboxsf   <options>  0   0
```

Replace `name_of_share` and `/path/to/mountpoint` with your individual setup (the directory for the mountpoint has to be created first). See the manpage for mount `<options>`. One possibility is to mount with `defaults`, or to give specific mount options (e.g. `rw, suid, exec, auto, users`).

On some systems the `vboxsf` kernel module is not yet loaded at the time `fstab` is read on boot. It may then help to append the `vboxsf` kernel module to `/etc/modules`.

Some systems may need option `comment=systemd.automount` in their fstab entry ([source](https://superuser.com/a/869652)).

#### 2. Mount with Virtual Box "automatic mounting":

In recent releases of Virtual Box we can also automatically mount shared folders on creation:

[image]

After a reboot of the guest this shared folder will be mounted to the guest directory `/media/<username>/sf_<name_of_share>` accessible to all users who had been made member of the group `vboxsf`.

Comment: How do you change the mount directory and mount prefix? Do you run some terminal commands in the HOST OS or the GUEST OS?

Comment: This feature requires that the "virtualbox-guest-utils" service has started, and on Ubuntu 14.04 this service starts later than the filesystems are mounted. This is the reason for "device not found" error when mounting the shares through fstab

Comment: @kolypto, that's a good observation.  Any idea of how to reorder their loading order?

Comment: @garromark, my only idea is to create an upstart script, which is quite simple. Another option is to put the same fstab entry, but add "noauto" so you just mount it manually.

Comment: @kolypto, thanks for getting back to me.  I actually found two competing solutions, only one of which worked for me: Option 1) (Worked for me), is, as you said, to put `noauto` in the fstab options and then to later mount typically in a startup script (such as .profile), Option 2) the main issue being that vboxsf isn't loaded prior to fstab running, append `vboxsf` to the file `/etc/modules`, asking the kernal to load the module prior to fstab being run.  Maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: I had the problem where the Shared Folders weren't automatically mounted on a Linux guest, couldn't work it out until I saw garromark's comment above about adding vboxsf to /etc/modules. Works perfectly now

Comment: @happyskeptic: thank you for confirming this behaviour. I added this to my answer so future visitors will find this easier.

Comment: thanks, I actually tried the 'vboxsf in /etc/modules' fix with option 2 (Virtualbox Auto mounting) and it worked there. So it seems that also the vboxsf kernel module isn't loaded when Virtualbox's guest additions try to mount the shared folders

Comment: For me works this:http://superuser.com/a/869652/145536

Comment: please remember to add your user to the vboxsf group. You may refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/add-user-to-existing-group

Comment: the first method worked for me by adding the `vboxsf` kernel module to `/etc/modules`. In `/etc/fstab` file, i provided with `uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g)` as `<options>`

Comment: For the sake of arguments and to reflect virtualbox case: i used to do this upon start `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) windows_share ~/shared/mount_point` and putting the following in /etc/fstab works: `windows_share /home/dev/shared/mount_point vboxsf rw 0 0` where dev is my user :)

Comment: Hello @Takkat; nicely written answer but it didn't work for me, the only thing that did work was adding `comment=systemd.automount` as in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/869652/145536) pointed out above.  I am using VirtualBox 5.2.2 and Kubuntu 17.10.  Since this seems to work for others, when there's a lot of red herrings here, would you mind integrating that piece of information into your highly-ranked answer?

Comment: @HostileFork: thank your for that hint, included.

Comment: Note: using GUI automount results in the owner being root. All changed to file permissions are overridden and, when I attempted to add my user to the group, nothing changed. I resolved the problem with an automount in fstab.

Answer (score 28):

1. Edit `/etc/rc.local`

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
   ```
2. Before `exit 0` type:

   ```
   mount.vboxsf windows_share /media/windows_share vboxsf
   ```
3. Save
4. *(Optional)* Create a shortcut to the desktop or home folder:

   ```
   ln -s /media/windows_share /home/freddy/Desktop
   ```

In order to boot without errors like pressing **S** to skip mount or press **M** to manually repair you may have to delete your entry in `fstab`

Comment: This is the ONLY way I have found to work, tried RC.Local with the regular mount command, tried FSTAB, tried Crontab w/ script. Huge Thanks!!

Comment: This worked for me too (opposed to the accepted answer, not quite sure why). So a big thank you from me! :)

Comment: Worked for me.  I edited `/etc/rc.local` with this `mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharename mountpoint`.

Comment: For the sake of arguments and to reflect virtualbox case: i used to do this upon start `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) windows_share ~/shared/mount_point` and ended up putting the following in /etc/rc.local to have it work: `mount -t vboxsf windows_share /home/dev/shared/mount_point` where dev is my user, FYI /etc/fstab also works!

Comment: Your answer has worked for me, but the directories get mounted as root. I changed the `mount` command in `rc.local` script to include my user id (`2000`): `mount.vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000 /home/mwittie/Dropbox Dropbox vboxsf`. PS If anyone is looking for a tutorial on how to turn on `rc.local` on Ubuntu 17.04 [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd) has worked for me. PPS I did not need to include vboxsf in `/etc/modules`.

Comment: @MikeWittie is this necessary? why not just use /etc/fstab?

Comment: @qodeninja as kolypto described the `virtualbox-guest-utils` is not running when `/etc/fstab` is loaded.

Comment: this works for me too. i just added "mount /path/to/mountpoint" and left the fstab entry. i don't review startup errors so I guess that doesn't bother me for now. I no longer have to mount then startup my server services after startup. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 8):

For newer **systemd** based systems you need alternative approaches - the simplest being one mentioned in another [answer](https://superuser.com/a/869652/74173) to another question - which basically says that you need to add a special `comment` option to the `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
src     /my_mount/src_host  vboxsf  auto,rw,comment=systemd.automount 0 0
```

However for the above to work on some systems you need to check the 'Auto-mount' box in  VirtualBox's Shared Folders->Add dialogue, which means you can end up with a few duplicate mounts of the directory.

For a cleaner mount - without duplicate directories nor the need for 'Auto-mount' - you need to use systemd's [mount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) and [automount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) directives. To do so create two entries in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` named after your desired mount point e.g. to match the fstab mount point above they would be named `my_mount-src_host.mount` and contain:

```
[Unit]
Description=VirtualBox shared "src" folder

[Mount]
What=src
Where=/my_mount/src_host 
Type=vboxsf
Options=defaults,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

and `my_mount-src_host.automount`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto mount shared "src" folder

[Automount]
Where=/my_mount/src_host
DirectoryMode=0775

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then they need enabling:

```
sudo systemctl enable  my_mount-src_host.automount
sudo systemctl enable  my_mount-src_host.mount
```

They will now mount on boot. If you want mount them immediately (provided the Shared Folders have been created) you can do so:

```
sudo systemctl start  my_mount-src_host.mount
```

Note if you have directories with odd names or dashes (-) in them then use `systemd-escape` to find the appropriately escaped name.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, your first solution with `comment=systemd.automount` option works also without the Automount VBox checked. I struggled for days before finding your solution, Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear - I've updated my answer to reflect your finding.

Comment: This one worked on Debian 9, the other ones didn't.

Answer (score 6):

After an exhausting morning trying all the above in Ubutntu 16.04 running in Virtualbox 5.0.20 unsuccessfully (particularly disappointed that the rc.local solution didn't work), it worked by:

1. Registering from Shared Folders menu of Virtualbox GUI the required directory but NOT automounting it or permanent mounting from Virtualbox. Otherwise the host dir is mounted by root and it's a pain to access by non-root users even from the admin group.
2. adding simple entry in fstab:

   ```
   [VirtuablBoxNameOfMount] /media/[guestOSuser]/[mountSubdir]    vboxsf   rw, noauto   0     1
   ```

   Note `noauto` option - otherwise boot loader fails as has been noted.
3. Add corresponding line to `/etc/sudoers` as follows by using command visudo from within guest OS:

   ```
   ALL ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/mount /media/[guestOSuser]/[mountSubdir]/
   ```

This will allow non-root processes to specifically mount this (as fstab can't mount with 'user' option ...)

4. Add corresponding line to .profile of user:

   ```
   sudo mount /media/[guestOSuser]/[mountSubdir]/
   ```

Now the selected host subdir is ready-mounted for the selected user upon login!

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for `noauto`?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  But in addition, I also had to add "vboxsf" to /etc/modules to make sure that .profile didn't run the mount commands before the vboxsf is ready.

Comment: instead of using sudo, add 'user' to the fstab option and any user can mount the filesystem

Comment: see http://pclosmag.com/html/issues/200709/page07.html for info on updating fstab, the comments here were only partially helpful. The fourth column in fstab is a comma sep list of options add user (uid=xxx) to that list e.g. noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000

Comment: There is a blank between rw, noauto
which  results in a parse error. without the blank the sample worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I tried the rc.local solution but couldn't get it to work.
However I discovered the problem seems to be related to the folder you run the command from (no idea why).  So I added a line to change the directory to my home folder before the mount command, and now it works.

So, my windows share is called `Dropbox`, my mountpoint is `/home/jamie/Dropbox`, my user name is `jamie`, this is what I put in rc.local:

```
cd /home/jamie
mount.vboxsf /home/jamie/Dropbox Dropbox vboxsf
exit 0
```

Comment: Brilliant! thanks. After struggling with the other solutions this worked first time!

Comment: I had to add a `sleep 2` before mounting the device.

Answer (score 2):

I do it of a very similar mode at was proposed above but these script create the required and mount or unmount the shared folder with the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Mount automatically even shared folder on startup and unmount it at shutdown.
#
# VirtualBox (c) 2015 by Oracle Systems Inc.
#
####

# Check user privileges.
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "This script must run at ROOT user!" \
        "\nPlease, use 'sudo', 'visudo' or any other to run it."
    exit 1
fi

# Check paramas from caller.
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "Auto-Mount selected shared folder of VirtualBox machine." \
        "\nUsage:" \
        "\n    VBoxShared <drive_one> <drive_two> <...>"
    exit 2
fi

declare EVENT=          # This set the ACTION: -m OR -u
declare -a DRIVES=()

# Processing each param:
for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
        "-m"|"--mount")
            if [[ -z ${EVENT} ]]; then
                EVENT=-m
            else
                exit 318        # parameters at conflict!
            fi
            ;;

        "-u"|"--umount")
            if [[ -z ${EVENT} ]]; then
                EVENT=-u
            else
                exit 318        # parameters at conflict!
            fi
            ;;

        *)
            DRIVES=("${DRIVES[@]}" "${arg}")
            ;;
    esac
done
unset arg

[[ -z ${EVENT} ]] && exit 1             # ERROR: No se ha establecido la acción a realizar.
[[ "${#DRIVES[@]}" -gt 0 ]] || exit 1   # ERROR: No se han indicado las unidades a manejar.

# Process each shared folder stored on '${DRIVES}' array
for drive in "${DRIVES[@]}"; do
    DEST="/media/sf_${drive}"

    case "${EVENT}" in
        "-m")
            [[ -d ${DEST} ]] || (mkdir ${DEST} && chown root:vboxsf ${DEST} && chmod 770 ${DEST})
            mount -t vboxsf ${drive} ${DEST}
            ;;

        "-u")
            if [[ `df --output=target | grep "${DEST}"` > /dev/null ]]; then
                umount -f ${DEST}
                rm -rf "${DEST}"
            fi
            ;;
    esac
    unset DEST
done
unset drive

unset EVENT
unset DRIVES
exit 0
```

Save it as `/opt/.scripts/VBoxShared.sh`.

Make sure that this can be runned. On shell type:

```
sudo chmod a+x /opt/.scripts/VBoxShared.sh
```

Now, we add a line that run this script on `rc.local`:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and we add these line before last line (`exit 0`):

```
. /opt/.scripts/VBoxShared.sh --mount <SharedFolder1> [<SharedFolder2> <SharedFolder3> ...]
```

Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) and close it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>)

At this point, we mount automatically all shared folder listed on `<SharedFolder>` at startup.

For unmount it, we only need type:

`sudo nano /etc/rc6.d/K99-vboxsf-umount.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

. /opt/.scripts/VBoxShared --umount <SharedFolder1> [<SharedFolder2> <SharedFolder3> ...]

exit 0
```

Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) and close (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>)

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc6.d/K99-vboxsf-auto.sh
```

And that's all!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution.

As root (I.E. sudo su) Go to home folder (cd ~) and create a cron file:
vi cronjobs
Add the following
@reboot   sleep 15; mount -t vboxsf app /mnt/app

Save file

Note: replace app with your shared folder name and /mnt/app where you want to mount it.  In this case I created the folder app under mount (mkdir app) first.

To enable your cron as root (for above filename)
crontab cronjobs

Make sure cron is active:
crontab -l

reboot and it will be mounted.  15 second sleep allows enough time for everything to be ready for the mount.

Comment: rc.local in the accepted answer was removed in a recent release of Ubuntu. This alternative solution works :)

Answer (score 1):

(In my case, my host OS is Mac OS X and my guest OS is ubuntu)

None of the above solutions, and the solutions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest) worked for me. There was a problem with all of them.

Here is what I finally did to solve the issue:

1- I created a shared folder in VirtualBox UI, pointing to a folder named `VMShares` in my Mac OS, naming it `wd`

2- Then I installed Ubuntu Guest Addition tools (restart required)

3- Then I made a folder in my guest OS as the mount point (in my case the name was `/home/fashid/host`)

4- Then I ran:

```
sudo VBoxControl sharedfolder list
```

This was the command to be ensured that the share is available to the guest OS, meanwhile you still need to mount it in your guest OS to make it actually available.

It will show something like:

```
Shared Folder mappings (1):
01 - VMShares
```

This is the trick! It is showing the actual name you need to put in below command to actually mount it and make it available in your guest OS:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf VMShares /home/farshid/myshares
```

Did you realize the point? I did not use wd anywhere later. In step 3, I needed to pickup the actual (host) folder name instead of the arbitrary name I asigned in GUI dialog box.

Via above steps, my issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this thread when, after updating to Ubuntu LTS-18 *(and making no changes whatever to VirtualBox, and after reinstalling the extensions and blah-de-blah),* auto-mount stopped working.  The `sf_xxx` directories were present in `/media/` but none of them were actually mounted.

Attempts to mount them in `/etc/fstab` (as suggested by VirtualBox's own documentation) didn't work:  the boot failed into "emergency mode," even when I had modified the `/etc/modules` file.

What *did* eventually work – although I regard it as a stinkin' hack – is the `crontab` trick described above.

To this day, I have no idea "what broke."

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue where I could see the shared folder, but there were no files in it.  So I did a hack similar to what was shown above:

I made sure that my user was in the correct group(s), and that there was an entry in fstab for mounting the share, and that the permissions were set correctly, and that auto-mount was on in VirtualBox settings, but still no files to be seen.
So I opened up the Startup Applications app in the Ubuntu 18.04 GUI and created a task that simply ran "sudo mount -a" right at startup.  For whatever reason the shared folder was not being mounted correctly when fstab was automatically parsed at boot, so re-mounting everything seemed to fix the problem.  Now I can see the files in the share.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the solutions here and none worked.

What worked was to install supervisor and run a python script.

## install supervisor

`apt-get install supervisor`

## python script (mine was at /home/ubuntu/shared_folders.py)

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

shared_folder = '/home/ubuntu/shared'

file_count = len(os.listdir(shared_folder))

mnt_command = 'mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 shared-folder ' + shared_folder
if file_count == 0:
        # mount
        subprocess.Popen(mnt_command, shell=True)

time.sleep(3600)
```

## create config file for supervisor

`nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/sharedfolders.conf`

`[program:shared_folders]
command=python shared_folders.py
directory=/home/ubuntu
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
numprocs=1
numprocs_start=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=1
startretries=3
exitcodes=0,2
stopsignal=TERM
stopwaitsecs=10
;user=pavelp
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/qlistener-stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stdout_capture_maxbytes=0
stdout_events_enabled=false
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/qlistener-stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
stderr_capture_maxbytes=0
stderr_events_enabled=false
environment=APPLICATION_ENV=development
serverurl=AUTO`

## open supervisorctl

`sudo supervisorctl`

## read configuration

`reread`

## add configuration

`add shared_folders`