# Virtualbox xp guest can't modify or delete files on shared folders

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, windows-xp

I'm running VirtualBox 4.1.18 on Ubuntu 12.10 host and running a Win XP SP3 guest I cannot rename or delete files once created.
Win guest complain with the error :

E:\ is not accessible
Incorrect function

Just the host can.
First of all, I wanna say clearly that I followed instructions :

- Guest Addiction installed (3 times) in xp guest
- ubuntu user added to vboxusers group
- Specified the folder to share in VM settings both before and after running the xp guest
- I tried also running Virtualbox as root, same error.

Furthermore, instead of sharing an NTFS partition, I even tried using a normal folder in ubuntu filesystem, owned by ubuntu user.
Same error.

The sharing always works, but the modify / deletions of files don't.
I read several forums on the web and a lot of people are reporting this as a bug for YEARS...is this possible ??
After new versions and releases still this is not working ?
Anybody had ever found a workaround for this ?

Please help...
TIA
Enrico

One other piece of information - if  I double-click on the file to execute the default action (e.g., double-click on .txt opens file in notepad, double-click on .RDP runs RDP file), it works fine.  It's only if I try to edit such files that I get the behavior.

Two things that are odd about this setup (to me):

1) if I browse directly from start/run to \vboxsrv\sharename, it opens \VBOXSVR\sharename (note the change in name - srv vs. SVR below):

[image: Screenshot showing difference in share names]

2) when I open it in this manner (as opposed to browsing to the assigned drive letter (e.g., double-clicking on the E: drive (in my case) under My Computer), as shown in image above, I *can* edit the files!

To reproduce on XP Guest:

- Browse to a file on the shared folder (e.g., test.txt) - you must
  browse to the drive letter assigned to the share.
- right-click and select Edit from the context menu.

Comment: You tagged your question with *"Samba"* - how do you mount and access your shares? Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup

Comment: I just wanna add that folders created by xp guest are saw by the host with 775 umask, and files as 664.
Changing both to 777 doesn't solve the error.

Comment: Thanks Takkat, but I'm using an XP guest from an ubuntu host...

Comment: @enrico Why did you tag Samba? Samba transfers via network connection, while VirtualBox shared folders use file system drivers. They have nothing to do with each other. Samba **is** an alternative or workaround.

Comment: Samba tag removed, but question still unanswered...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something silly, but when I connected a hard drive I needed to set write permissions in the Virtual Machine settings.

Comment: Under Storage VM Settings you can only specify VIRTUAL Hard disks.
For a real existing partion or folder you have to use the Shared Folder setting.

Answer (score 0):

well, here is the solution i found. This worked for me for the ubuntu 16.04 version and hopefully should work for any other version due to the consise logic behind this.
first open the terminal and type following commands one by one in sequence:

```
sudo passwd root
```

and set the password for root after the prompt
now make yourself root by typing

```
su root
```

now go to the directory VirtualBox by repeatedly using cd .. command
it will look like this
root@speedious-VirtualBox:/#

now go to the media file inside this directory
type

```
cd media
```

now use the following command to delete the shared folder named 'sf_filename'

```
rm -r sf_filename
```

That's it..  done!
The reason behind this is that only root has the permission to delete such files as can be verified in properties section of that folder.

Hope this will help you.