# Change mount point of virtualbox shared folder

Tags: mount, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have a shared folder set up between virtualbox and my windows 7 host machine. I have a test.txt file that I created in Windows and it shows up appropriately in my Ubuntu VM. Virtualbox mounts the shared folder in `/media/sf_share` (the name I gave to the shared folder in the virtualbox settings was `share`). I want to move the mount point from `/media/sf_share` to simply `/srv` so that on my windows host I can edit files and they show up under `/srv`. How can I accomplish this?

**

### What I've tried:

**

I've edited `/etc/fstab` to look like this:

```
share /srv vboxsf defaults 0 0
```

After doing this I used the command `mount -a`, also I rebooted, and I rebooted again with the virtualbox shared folder settings to NOT auto-mount.

I read there is an issue with filesystems being mounted before virtualbox utilities are loaded, so I added `vboxsf` to my `/etc/modules` and then repeated the steps above.

None of them reproduce the correct content in /`srv`. When I issue `mount -a` AFTER I have edited the `fstab` I can sometimes get it to work. I don't know what I'm doing differently each time, but sometimes after I edit `fstab`, issue `mount -a` without rebooting I can see the files there. After a reboot though the files are gone again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mount a VirtualBox shared folder at startup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup)

Comment: @Takkat I can mount the shared folder just fine. That is not the issue. I want to change the mount point (or any other solution that allows me to develop on my host machine and have the changes appear in `/srv` in my vm).

Answer (score 7):

You have to change the "Guest properties" to modify the mount prefix and base directory used for the shared folders.

See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto
and https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-guestprops

**An important note, though:**
Both properties detailed in the first link have default values when not set or cleared:
`/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix` defaults to `sf_` if not set.
Set `/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir` defaults to `/media` if not set

As a consequence, you have to set `MountPrefix` to `/` if you do not want the `sf_` prefix, as trying to set it to "" will in fact clear the property and put it back to its default value.

Comment: I was going crazy trying to figure out how to set `MountPrefix` to an empty value, setting it to `/` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check `/etc/fstab`? I'm not too sure how virtualbox shares, so if changing the mount point breaks the sharing, you could change it back & bind mount `/media/sf_share` to `/srv`

Info on bind mounting & fstab:

> https://serverfault.com/questions/613179/how-do-i-do-mount-bind-in-etc-fstab
>
> > If I had a volume mounted at /media/3tb-vol1/Private/, and I wanted to bind it to /srv/Private I have a /etc/fstab like this.
> >
> > `/media/3tb-vol1/Private/ /srv/Private        none    bind`

Of course, I don't know the details of VirtualBox's sharing. I'm not sure how & when `/media/sf_share` gets mounted, if it's not ready when `fstab` is, it might not be mounted in time to be bound...?

Comment: And what would I be looking for in fstab?

Comment: `/media/sf_share`, that's what you want to change right?

Comment: That does not appear is `fstab`. I tried `mount --bind /media/sf_share /srv` and that appears to be working.

Comment: Well, after a reboot all the contents were lost from `/srv`

Comment: a terminal `mount` would only be in effect until a reboot. Maybe add it to `/etc/fstab` if it exists at bootup, or to a login script or a one-liner script file (to run when needed) if it's not there until later

Comment: I tried adding it and it didn't work: inside fstab `/media/sf_share /srv auto bind 0 0` no luck

Comment: Please see the edit to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Nawak's answer, I finally managed to get it done. I had already tried so many solutions (based on `/etc/fstab/` and setting some `/etc/rc.local`) but this one was the one that worked.

I just ran the following commands (from the host machine):

```
VBoxManage guestproperty set "Ubuntu 16" /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix /
VBoxManage guestproperty set "Ubuntu 16" /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir srv
```

Where `Ubuntu 16` is the name of my VM. In order to check that these properyies where applied properly, you can run:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate "Ubuntu 16"
```