# A shared folder doesn't mount upon startup of Ubuntu on Oracle VM Virtualbox

Tags: mount, virtualbox, windows-7, fstab

I have a PC with Windows 7x64. I installed Oracle VM (v. 5.2.20). In the VM I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and created a shared folder in the VM. The shared folder has name `vp` and refers to `d:\vp` folder on Windows.

In Ubuntu, I set up auto-mounting and now this folder is displayed in Ubuntu as `sf_vp`.

Next, I want to mount this shared folder to my folder on Ubuntu `/home/roman/vp`.

I can do it on working Ubuntu via the command:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vp ~/vp
```

It works successfully, but when I add this line:

```
vp /home/roman/vp vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000
```

into `/etc/fstab` file and reboot Ubuntu, it somehow doesn't mount upon loading Ubuntu, if writes "FAILED mounting ...".

And if I add this string into `/etc/fstab` and execute a command

```
sudo mount -a
```

without a reboot, it also works and the folder `/home/roman/vp` is mounted successfully.

Could you clarify me, what doesn't mounting work upon loading Ubuntu?

I want to repeat, Ubuntu is installed in Oracle VM and vp is a shared folder, it set up in Oracle VM too.

Comment: By default the VBox shared folders are mounted to /media without any entries in /etc/fstab Have you checked there?  I recommend removing entries from /etc/fstab and allowing vbox to do its thing.

Comment: The matter is that I'm going to use Docker for web-development and keep my project sources in shared folders. I want to work on Windows and use VM with Ubuntu and docker as a web-server. Unfortunately, some docker-containers aren't created without mounting a shared folder to a folder in /home/roman/ (that's my user folder). Folders can be mount successfully via mount command if Ubuntu already works. But they can't be mounted upon starting of Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm... now that's a wrinkle. Does a symlink work? ````ln -s /media/sf_vp /home/roman/vp```` It might. Docker is a bit of an anomaly but symlinks are usually transparent on unix.

Comment: Unfortunately, docker doesn't work correctly with symlinks.

Comment: Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/563031/change-mount-point-of-virtualbox-shared-folder