# When in Linux boot process are filesystems mounted from /etc/fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab, kernel

**Question:**

### When in Ubuntu Linux boot process are filesystems (from /etc/fstab) mounted?

**Rational:**

I defined the following *shared-folders* on my *Ubuntu VirtualBox VM*.

```
openstack@ubuntu:~$ grep vboxsf /etc/fstab
tmp     /home/openstack/shared/tmp      vboxsf  defaults        0       0
images  /home/openstack/shared/images   vboxsf  defaults        0       0
openstack@ubuntu:~$
```

Mounting them from the shell is no problem.

However, during the *boot process,* their mounting fails:

[image]

Upon entering maintenance mode, I verify the problem to be that the `vboxsf` module is *not* loaded in the kernel (and subsequently, after it's loaded, the `mount` succeeds):

[image]

I want to solve this by creating a new `rc` file, that will execute the `modprobe vboxsf` command before `/etc/fstab` is read.

So, I tried executing `modprobe vboxsf` at the start of *run-level 2*:

```
openstack@ubuntu:/etc/rc2.d$ ls -ls /etc/rc2.d/S10modprobe-vboxsf
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Apr 28 14:36 /etc/rc2.d/S10modprobe-vboxsf -> ../init.d/modprobe-vboxsf
openstack@ubuntu:/etc/rc2.d$ cat ../init.d/modprobe-vboxsf
/sbin/modprobe vboxsf
openstack@ubuntu:/etc/rc2.d$ ls -ls ../init.d/modprobe-vboxsf
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22 Apr 28 14:33 ../init.d/modprobe-vboxsf
openstack@ubuntu:/etc/rc2.d$
```

but the *shared folders* still fail to mount from `/etc/fstab.`

Google did not bear fruit, so - my question is:

### How do I load the `vboxsf` module to the Ubuntu kernel, ***before*** `/etc/fstab` is read and file-systems are mounted?

Comment: Be aware that the answer, and even the behaviour shown in the question, are radically different on Ubuntu version 15.  The handling of failed `auto` mounts, the interaction with `fsck`, the point at which mount units are activated, the way in which such dependencies can be expressed, and even the mechanisms available for loading modules, are very different with systemd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `vboxsf` to `/etc/modules` (check to see if it is already there first, though I have a feeling it is not) and see if that helps.

Otherwise, a similar question has been asked over at askubuntu. See if any answers there help you at all:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup

Edit to try and answer the question as asked in the title: I am not sure when exactly mounts take place during the boot process, though I suspect it happens after (most?) kernel modules are loaded, since at least some file systems require certain modules to be loaded in order to work (eg, nfs, vboxfs, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the `/etc/modules` suggestion, @yzhernand. Indeed, after adding `vboxsf` to `/etc/modules`, the shared file-systems get mounted during boot.

Comment: Excellent! Glad that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:

The answer for those who found the question by google search for phrase similar to the title of the question.

On Linux with `systemd` (at least on systems I use) it is `systemd` that processes mounts (below two variants of listing system output, where entries are found depends on whether messages already moved from `ring buffer` to `syslog`, `/media/drive` is from `/etc/fstab`:

```
dmesg | grep media
dmesg -F /var/log/syslog | grep media
               [    4.494745] systemd[1]: Mounting /media/drive...
               [    4.499664] systemd[1]: Mounted /media/drive.
```

P.S. `systemd` is started right after kernel is loaded fully (AFAIK).