# Setting up shared drive through virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-8, shared-folders

I have Ubuntu 14.04  running as a virtual machine through Virtualbox and I'm trying to set up a directory to share with the Host (windows 8.1). Under settings I have specified a windows directory that I want to be shared:

[image]

However, when I boot up the virtual machine I can't see any reference to it under `devices` - just `VBOXADDITIONS` and `Computer`. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install virtual box tools in Ubuntu?

Comment: This may help your: http://askubuntu.com/a/252865/3940

Comment: @prakharsingh95, yes I have the virtual box tools installed

Comment: @Takkat great thanks - that seems to be it...I will try when home tonight