# Can't see shared folders in VirtualBox Ubuntu VM?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I've been using VirtualBox for the first time to run Ubuntu and am having some problems with shared folders. I've done everything that I can think of after googling and looking around but still can't seem to find them anywhere.

- I've added the user to "vboxsf"
- I've installed the guest additions
- I have permanent, Auto-Mount folders created on my host PC and shown in the "shared folders" at the top

However, I cannot find these folders anywhere on the guest OS that I can use to access and bring files across/share them with my normal windows OS.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest and https://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup

Comment: Did you restart the guest OS?

Comment: @George - Yes I did!

Comment: Then re-install the Guest Additions again, might be a glitch!

Comment: @Takkat - Thanks for the links, however I tried to mount it following the steps and still got a "protocol error" which is strange..

Comment: @George - Just want to say, thanks so much! It now works! I didn't naturally think of reinstalling since I didn't think it was related to Guest Additions!

Answer (score 9):

## Short Answer:

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`

## Long Answer:

I had the same problem.

Assuming that we have already added the shared folder in the virtual box:

{

1) Machine -> Settings -> Shared Folders

2) Click on the "Add new shared folder" icon

[image]

3) Choose the path for the host folder you want to share (for example "C:\hostFolder")

4) Give "Folder Name" a name (for example "sharedFolderName")

5) Check "Auto-mount"

}

However, after starting the VM, there was nothing in my `/media/`.

But as soon as I ran:

`sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils`

I could see the sh_ folder:

`ls /media/`

Although you can access the content of your host folder through media, I suggest creating another folder:

`mkdir ~/guestFolder`

and then:

`sudo mount -t vboxsf sharedFolderName ~/guestFolder`

Now you can see content of the host folder here:

`ls ~/guestFolder`