# how to make connection between windows 10 and ubuntu

Tags: networking

i installed windows 10 and Ubuntu in different drives in my computer. i want to share files between these two operating systems. if you have any information to solve this problem, please help me.
my virtual box could not be connected and my windows 10 is 32 bit operating system.
so therefore i installed them in different drives.
please help me to connect them

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount a VirtualBox shared folder at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup)

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:networking] even though you say that both systems run on the same machine. Are Windows and Ubuntu both installed as host operating systems or is either of them a guest system inside a virtual machine running on the other?

Answer (score 0):

A very good way to do this is by configuring Samba to share a common folder, I am using a Windows 8.1 guest VM and my host is Ubuntu 17.10.

Verify if the `samba` package is installed:

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep samba
```

if it's not you can install it

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common samba-common-bin
```

Don't run it yet, you need to edit its configuration file first.

But before that, make a directory in Ubuntu that will be the folder to be shared to other Windows OS

```
mkdir /home/$USER/TEST
```

Edit samba config file located in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

**Browse at the end of the line in smb.conf file and add this:**

```
[TEST]
comment = Shared Directory
path = /path/to/directory in this example say /home/yien/TEST
read only = no
write list = @sambashare
directory mask = 0775
```

After this, add your current user (say, `yien`) to sambashare group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a yien sambashare
```

Then create a samba password to it:

```
sudo smbpasswd yien
```

Also change the folder ownership:

```
 chown yien:sambashare /home/yien/TEST
```

Here you need to run Samba:

```
sudo systemctl start smbd
```

Enable it at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable smbd
```

Now in your Windows VM just enable first network discovery and you will see your UBUNTU network. Simply login to it then you will see the folder TEST or the one you created.