# mount: can't find /home/paatubo/Desktop/vmshare in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, virtualbox, fstab, etc

I made a sharefolder on `vmbox`.

I typed

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf /home/paatubo/Desktop/vmshare/
```

But it showed the following message as response:

```
mount: can't find /home/paatubo/Desktop/vmshare in /etc/fstab
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: the error is saying it cant find your mount point in /etc/fstab.... see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? (Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the source folder on your mount command. I assume in this case it will be:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf **[shared folder on vmbox]** /home/paatubo/Desktop/vmshare/
```