# Change user in root permission popup

Tags: sudo, root, users

I'm in the `sudoers` file (`username ALL=(ALL) ALL`, but am not the root user on a machine.

When I want to install something from Ubuntu Software, or want to execute some other root operation from a GUI, I get the following popup:

[image: root popup]

This popup shows the root user (name redacted in image), not me. I have the permission to do this operation (I'm in the `sudoers` file after all), but the popup doesn't give me any option to change the user that should do the operation. How do I solve this? I can of course execute the corresponding command with `sudo` from the terminal, but I'd like to be able to use the GUI as well.

Comment: Have you tried your user's password? Not root's.

Comment: @Gryu, yes, that was my first thought :). Didn't work though.

Comment: Since @steeldriver 's answer links to a question that is almost exactly the same as mine, I've closed my own question as a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup is likely from PolicyKit rather than from `sudo` directly.

Although PolicyKit itself allows fine-grained control of authentication, the default configuration simply assumes that all members of the `sudo` and `admin` *unix-groups* should be treated as administrators; it doesn't consider the contents of `/etc/sudoers` or apply any per-user rules therein

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

You have two options: either simply add your user to the `sudo` group instead of using the `username ALL=(ALL) ALL` sudoers entry, or add a custom PolicyKit 
configuration file as described below

- [Change default user for authentication](https://askubuntu.com/a/542435/178692)

See also

- [policykit-1: members of group sudo become root with pkexec while ignoring /etc/sudoers](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=869922)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tomorrow. Looks promising!