# Linux authentication required password change for user

Tags: permissions, password

I have some little challenge for UBUNTU Admins. If I start "snap install chrome". I get an windows "Authentication Required" But this User "lokal_admin1" is for automatics install. I want to replace the user in the window, not the password. How do I change the user that appears in the window?

I have tried to log in with another user to install, but it does not work. The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME. And yes I have admin rights.

[image]

Comment: You know there is no *snap* package named `chrome`...

Comment: I think perhaps you are asking about the pkexec authentication dialog - if so, see [Change default user for authentication](https://askubuntu.com/a/542435/178692)