# How to add a member to my group with a permission to change my files?

Tags: user-management

Sometimes I use my CPU as a root user, but mostly as a non-privileged user. As a non-privileged user I also need to change files created by the root user.

Comment: Do your files have group-write permission? See: http://askubuntu.com/a/94864/158442, http://askubuntu.com/q/46331/158442

Comment: @muru: Yes,  the files  have group-write permission

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo` whenever you want to change files?

That way, you're normally a Standard user, but can be an Administrator.

Use `sudo -i` for graphical programs.

Comment: @ Tim: If I try using sudo as a non-privileged user, I get a message that the user is not a sudoer.

Comment: @TomasPeceny why can't you make that person a sudoer?

Comment: Because I seek for methods how to shorten the time when my CPUs are connected to the network through privileged users, see comments in http://askubuntu.com/questions/641099/how-to-use-sudo-from-a-standard-user.

Comment: Why does it matter that you are a privileged user if you need a password to do anything?

Comment: I see I have needlessly used  the particular example with files created by the root user.  But I wish to change files created by an other user of my group generally, also if he is not a privileged one. The question should have been: 'What commands are used for adding a member to my group with a permission to change my files?'. Thanks!