# How to use sudo from a standard user?

Tags: 12.04, sudo, user-management

If I try using sudo as a non-privileged user, I get a message that the user is not in the sudoers file. I know the Administrator password, but I do not know, how to use it from a non-privileged (Standard) user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pkexec` instead. If the current user doesn't have privileges, or if there are multiple users who can authorize an action, it will prompt you to select the user:

```
$ pkexec true              
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/true' as the super user
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  muru
 2.  sysad, (sysad)
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 1
Password:
```

`pkexec`, of course, does not follow the `sudo` configuration, but its own. However, if you added admin users by adding them to the `sudo` group, they will also be granted Polkit admin rights by Ubuntu's default configuration.

Comment: Is this implemented on all currently supported Ubuntus or only a certain version and later?  (Because that's relevant, if only 'cause it's tagged 12.04)

Comment: I don't have a 12.04 system around to check, but AFAIK, Polkit came along before 12.04. For example, see this question from 2011: http://askubuntu.com/q/78352/158442.

Comment: I am not sure how to configure the pkexec eg. for hibernating , see http://askubuntu.com/questions/641238/how-to-hibernate-from-a-non-privileged-user. A related discussion is http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25226/discussion-between-tomas-peceny-and-thomas-w .Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately with `pkexec` I don't see command output in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

To go from a nonprivileged user to a `sudo` user, you do not use `sudo`.

Instead, you first have to switch users.

Login as the other user with the following command from `nosudo` user (assuming `nosudo` is the nonprivileged user, `yessudo` is the sudoer):

```
su - yessudo
```

It will then prompt for the login password for `yessudo`.  After you login as `yessudo` you can run `sudo` commands from that user.  If at any time you exit out of that and return to the `nosudo` user, you have to do the command above again.

Comment: Note that this does not solve the problem of you not being in sudoers.  Also consider that it's probably that way for a reason, so you should reconsider the ramifications of going about this method.

Comment: @ Thomas W.:  Yes, I care for security and I will always switch back to the 'nosudo' user. I understand that the system cannot switch it back straight automatically .

Comment: @ Thomas W.: Is it not possible to enable using sudo from the standard user by adding somehow the standard user into a sudoers file?  Thanks!

Comment: @TomasPeceny yes, but at that point the user becomes a privileged user, and not a standard user.  Add the unprivileged user to the `sudo` group, and they'll have `sudo` access (`usermod -a -G sudo nosudo` is the command, where `nosudo` is the non-sudoers user from above).  Then, `nosudo` user should log out and log back in, thereby refreshing their groups membership.  (HOWEVER, while this would do what you achieve and give `sudo` access to the `nosudo` user, `pkexec` would be a better option if you want to keep `nosudo` as an unprivileged user)

Comment: @ Thomas W.: I see I have misunderstood the term 'sudoer'. I seek for a method how to shorten the time when I am connected to the network as the privileged user.  As far as possible without complicated configuring. Your answer appears to be really the proper solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: @ Thomas W.: But the 'sudo pm-hibernate' does not work this way (the CPU is working further, after a notice 'cannot find...'). Do you have an idea how to hibernate from a non-privileged user? Suspending works OK.

Comment: @TomasPeceny Hibernate doesn't work in all systems.  And I believe that's why they disable it.  You have to add your own user to the sudo group then execute with sudo.  Or use pkexec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25226/discussion-between-tomas-peceny-and-thomas-w).