# Having trouble opening images in Ubuntu command line

Tags: command-line, display, eog

When I'm trying to open an image in Ubuntu command line using the command `eog filename.jpg`, I get an error reading

```
Cannot open display:
```

Could someone please advise what else I need to run before this to open the image?

Note that I am accessing the machine directly, not `ssh`-ing in remotely.

Comment: What are the outputs of `echo "$DISPLAY"` and `echo "$XAUTHORITY"` ?

Comment: If you do this from command line you need to provide the DISPLAY: parameter

Comment: and please do not crosspost across stackexchange sites http://superuser.com/questions/1023875/having-trouble-opening-images-in-ubuntu-command-line

Comment: OP is probably trying to open images in TTY, not the GUI terminal. If you want to open images in TTY you need `fbi` package

Comment: something like this will work too: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/462043-problem-to-output-to-X-with-eog

Comment: Also, the post in Superuser was because I posted the question in the wrong location so I posted it again on here. I deleted the Superuser post.

Comment: @Serg make it an answer please ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As it was found out in the comments , OP actually wanted to open images in full-tty environment ,i.e., not in graphical environment.

Natively there are no apps that will allow to open images in full-text environment, however  one can install `fbi` package with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install fbi
```

The fbi package operates on rendering the image and writing it into framebuffer memory location , which is reference by `/dev/fb0` device.

To ensure you don't need `sudo` privilege to  run `fbi`, [add yourself to the video group](https://askubuntu.com/q/79565/295286) with the following command:

```
  sudo usermod -a -G video  $USER
```

Logout and log back in. At this point you can open images with:

```
 fbi path/to/image.png
```

For more advanced use of package `fbi` check out [one of my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/706172/295286)  about setting TTY background.