# Different results for "groups" vs "groups myusername"?

Tags: permissions, users, chgrp

I want to add my user `patrick` to the `plex` group, so I used the command

`usermod -a -G plex patrick`

Great!  When I type `groups patrick` I get

`patrick : patrick adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd sambashare lpadmin plex`

However, when I then tried to `chgrp` a directory from `patrick` to `plex` it returns a permission denied! If I type in `groups` with no username specified, the output returns

`patrick adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd sambashare lpadmin`

with no group `plex` at the end.  (And I'm logged in as user `patrick`)

What did I do incorrectly?  Why am I seeing different results for `groups` vs `groups username`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `man` page (`man groups`):

```
DESCRIPTION

       Print  group  memberships  for  each  USERNAME  or,  if  no USERNAME is
       specified, for the current process (which  may  differ  if  the  groups
       database has changed).
```

Group membership is set at process creation time (login time). SInce you were not a member of the `plex` group when you logged in, `groups` doesn't list it as part of the current process. `groups patrick` consults the (updated with `plex` group membership) groups database.

To use the `plex` group membership, create a new process by logging out and in, or by executing the `bash` `newgrp plex` command.

Comment: Not only did I miss it in the man page, I also missed it in the very instructions I followed to add the user to the group: https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/how-to-add-existing-user-to-an-existing-group.  Thanks for the help.