# How to add an existing user to an existing user group and verify it is added?

Tags: users, groups

I am running Ubuntu 17.04.

I am simply trying to add my existing user account to the lxd group and I expect to be able to verify that I am in that group with the "groups" command.

I tried the things in [How to add existing user to an existing group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/how-to-add-existing-user-to-an-existing-group) but I am puzzled by what I found:

Listing what my current groups:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ groups
drunkard adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Trying to add lxd group to my user account:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ sudo usermod -a -G lxd drunkard
[sudo] password for drunkard:
```

List the current groups:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ groups
drunkard adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Sure. I have to log out and login again.  So as a short cut I will login as a subshell with:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ su - drunkard
Password:
```

Now, surely the groups listed should include lxd:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ groups
drunkard lxd
```

Huh? What happened? Where did the existing groups go? I used the -a option!

Ok, being confused, I exited that shell and tried this:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ sudo usermod -a -G lxd,drunkard,adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare drunkard
drunkard@thebar:~$ su - drunkard
Password: 
drunkard@thebar:~$ groups
drunkard adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare lxd
```

ok, there they are, but then logging completely out and back in again, I see "lxd" is missing:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ groups
drunkard adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Hunting around, I found this command:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ getent group lxd
lxd:x:136:drunkard
```

Apparently my user account *is* in the lxd group, but why in the heck is the groups command not showing it?

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ groups
drunkard adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

What nuance am I missing here?

---

EDIT #1:  The lxc command seems to indicate that I am not in lxd group:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ lxc launch ubuntu: first-machine
Permission denied, are you in the lxd group?
drunkard@thebar:~$ getent group lxd
lxd:x:136:drunkard
drunkard@thebar:~$ sudo adduser drunkard lxd
[sudo] password for drunkard: 
The user `drunkard' is already a member of `lxd'.
drunkard@thebar:~$
```

---

EDIT #2:

After rebooting, I am now able to see my user account added to the group and the `lxc` command works without sudo. Why? I should have to only logout and log back in again, not a full reboot, right?

Comment: I don't know what happened to your groups. You can verify the groups your user is belonging to with `grep drunkard /etc/group`.

Comment: Yes that is what is puzzling me. I've got it fixed, but it is disconcerting that a reboot is what was required (hearkens back to MS Windows days).