# Can't write in a shared directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, groups

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and want to create a shared directory, but after creating it, I'm not able to create files in it even if I'm member of the group.

Here is what I did and what I got:

[image]

It works when running `sudo su` instead of `sudo`, but normally I should have the required permissions.

What is the source of the issue?

Comment: You are sure you are member of the group? Do `id` to find out. You have to log out and in again to reload the group membership!

Comment: Please note that `/usr/local/share` is meant for read-only architecture-independent data files (see [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREARCHITECTUREINDEPENDENTDATA) for more details). This isn't supposed to be user data, but rather applications' data. You seem to misunderstand its purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a file in that directory required that you'll be either `root` or in group `music`.

It seems like the reason you failed to create the file, is that your user isn't included in group `music`.

- You can check that by running `id` command - which will show the groups you are member in (thanks for @ridgy comment)
- As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/79566/544264) you can add your user to a group using:

  ```
  sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
  ```

> Note: You might need to logout/login in order to update the group list of your user.

Comment: @PerlDuck - the OP execute the command `> /usr/local/share/Music/test_file` - the command will create a new file the right permissions exists. (note the `>` at the beginning)

Comment: @PerlDuck - to test it yourself, try for example running `> /etc/test_PerlDuck` as regular user on your machine, and see the error you'll get

Comment: @PerlDuck - NP :) - do you agree with my answer now?

Comment: Yes. My suggestion for the OP would be: 1) make sure (by issuing `id`) you're member of `music`. If not, use `usermod …` and logout/in for the changes to take effect. That's about what you wrote.

Comment: @PerlDuck - thanks for your comment, I've edited my answer to be clearer (as you suggested)

Comment: Well, ***I*** would accept your answer now ;-)

Comment: That _Foot of the Rainbow_ hat looks … umm … funny.

Comment: Executing `newgrp` will apply changes made to `/etc/group` without having to log out/in, it launches a new shell instance with the updated group memberships. (It's actually a new instance launched as a child of the old, so `exit` will drop you back to the previous, outdated-groups parent, and of course it won't affect any of the rest of the session, including other shells or the GUI.)

Comment: (Actually, let me amend that: Executing `newgrp <groupname>` will launch a child shell instance which has the user as a member of the named group, assuming the relevant changes have been made to `/etc/group` and friends. For some reason a bare `newgrp` doesn't pick up changes, though I thought it used to.)