# How to replace Apache2's main page?

Tags: apache2, webserver, development

How I can change Apache2's main page to a custom page of my own?

Comment: Remove the this file `/var/www/html/index.html` and add your own `/var/www/html/myown.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the file `/var/www/html/index.html` and replace it with your own `/var/www/html/myown.html`, and restart `apache`. Or simply replace the contents of the `/var/www/html/index.html` with yours.

**NOTE:**

Your file will also be called `index.html` not `myown.html` as I have used it here!

Comment: Add yourself to the www-data group, then change file group ownership to www-data group, then restart apache and logout and login again!

Comment: What im need to do if system cant give me acsess to file?

Comment: How i can exactly add myself to the www data group?

Comment: @SaintDude: https://askubuntu.com/q/79565/566421