# Using awk to append text to the end of a line in /etc/group

Tags: bash, scripts

I am writing a script to automate some tasks and I need to add a user to a group in /etc/group. I'm trying to use this command:

```
sudo bash -c "awk '{if (/^moli/) {$0=$0"$uservar,"}; print' /etc/group > /etc/group"
```

The issue I'm running into is I get

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if (/^moli/) {-bash=-bashtestuser1,}; print
awk: cmd. line:1:                     ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {if (/^moli/) {-bash=-bashtestuser1,}; print
awk: cmd. line:1:                                             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

If I change the `' '` to `""` I get: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

Comment: What is the sense of using `bash -c` here? Can't you just do `awk ... | sudo tee /etc/group` ? However, I would strongly suggest not to manually edit `/etc/group` file. If you do anything wrong, you might lock yourself out of your system. The least you have to do is make a backup of the file. Also, what is `$uservar`? Seems you rather want to use `sudo sed -i ...`

Comment: Do not edit `/etc/group` manually! Rather use `usermod` command. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/how-to-add-existing-user-to-an-existing-group).

Comment: I tried `usermod -a -G moli username` as a test. I checked to see if the user showed up in /etc/group but they're not there.

Comment: You might need to logout/login to see the changes I guess, that is also written in the answer from the link ;-)

Comment: It doesn't show in /etc/groups but if I run `groups username` it shows there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues in your small code:

- Single quotes inside double quotes do not prevent variable substitution.
  So, `$0` expands to `/bin/bash`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169508/single-quote-within-double-quotes-and-the-bash-reference-manual).
- You're actually really lucky that your command failed!! If working, it would have emptied your `/etc/group` file and you would have serious problems.
  In the moment you issue `command > file`, `file` gets opened and emptied for writing, and your `command` will see an empty file.

  Better use `> file.temp && mv file.temp file` or `awk -i inplace ...`.
- Instead of adding `bash` variables directly in  `awk` code, use `awk -v var=$var` option and use `var` inside `awk`.

---

**So, what to do ?**

You don't need this duplicate quoting hell, you could simply use:

```
sudo awk -i inplace '...' file
```

or

```
awk '...' file | sudo tee file.temp && sudo mv file.temp file
```

or for your case the better suited `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i '...' file
```

---

**However**, you should not change `/etc/group` manually at all.

Add a user with `usermod` (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/how-to-add-existing-user-to-an-existing-group)):

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
```