# Use of Diffrent terminals

Tags: tty

I have searched a lot about it but could not get an answer. I read somewhere that linux Ubuntu has 6 or 7 terminals.

We can start them by pressing -

```
Ctrl+Alt+(F1-F6)
```

and to get back to GUI-

```
Ctrl+Alt+F7
```

So what i want to know is what is the difference between these 6 different terminals , and how can we use them as per to different purposes??

Comment: i have voted to close it, got the answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/377232/192102

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact there are not only 6 or 7 ttys, there are many more. You could see them, try

```
ls /dev/tty* | wc -l
```

All the consoles are not always active. You need to activate `ttyN` in order to switch to it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F N</kbd>. You can activate any tty with `openvt` command also. See [man openvt.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/openvt.1.html)

Reason why there so many ttys, may have historical baskground. In old days Linux was used in terminals (without X server).

- To do multiple tasks at the same time it was indispensable to have more than one ttys.
- due to any accidentally break, it was required to have another tty from where system could be monitored.
- Even to read more than one man pages, different ttys were needed.

Nowadays for most users don't need that many — in fact most users never see anything but first 6 ttys to be available for CUI login and the virtual console that X is running on. As [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385831/use-of-diffrent-terminals/385838#385838) mentioned all these terminals are mostly identical.

But there are a few people who patch their kernel to allow more than 63 consoles(special ttys), because they run large machines with many hardware consoles.

Comment: yeah there are 103, can you tell me what kind of multiple tasks ??

Comment: There may be many different type. For simplest example consider a situation, to write a code and to run and monitoring its output how it is using system resources. Please keep in mind you don't have a X system and multiple windows.

Comment: +1 for explanation . thanks .. now i understand how it is useful in terms of multitasking.

Comment: I got the answer..

Comment: `ls -la /dev/ | awk '{print $NF}' | grep "^tty" | wc -l` is a funny way to go about it. `ls /dev/tty* | wc -l` does the same thing. You're using awk to undo the damage done by adding `-l` to `ls` for no reason.

Comment: @StevenKath You are correct. I did that long time back, can't remember the reason if any. I am on mobile device, will edit it as  I get a chance. Thank You.

Comment: @souravc Well, I sure wasn't expecting a 30 minute response time on a 3-year-old thread. You are a true soldier.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the 6 terminals -by default-. It is up to the user to think of use cases.

On a server setup I have seen these used to automate a login after booting up to start software. It is also possible to have the desktop to show more than 1 desktop manager: Unity on tty7, KDE on tty6 and XFCE on tty5 (but installation wise it might be a bit more difficult than it used to be).

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Terminals are provided as a convenience. They come in very handy when troubleshooting problems with the GUI.

On servers that do not have a GUI they are indispensable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console