# How to install different desktop managers on different tty

Tags: desktop-environments, tty

How do I install different desktop managers like `Unity`, `KDE`, `XFCE` etc in different ttys so that I could toggle them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F N</kbd>, where `N` is `4,5,6 etc.` [In this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385831/use-of-diffrent-terminals/385838#385838) I got the hint of such possibility. But I could not found a good documentation of the same.

Comment: I have seen 1 example with the new upstart Ubuntu uses. When you install XMBC and have a desktop the desktop takes tty7 and XMBC uses tty8. This topic: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=141369 page 21 is where it gets interesting. By the way: it seems that lightdm is hardcoded to tty7. I will try to find a more complete answer.

Comment: I saw the the example, thanks for it. I will be waiting for a better answer.

Comment: Have you checked this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/416825/how-to-quick-switch-between-desktop-environments-in-the-running-desktop-session . It is not a permanent solution, but it may have some advance

Comment: @Sneetsher I was not exactly looking for this. Any way, thanks.