# What's the difference between Ctrl-Alt-F1 and Ctrl-Alt-F3?

Tags: command-line, console

In Ubuntu, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> brings you to a console login.When you press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> it also brings you to a console login. My question is, why use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> over <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or vice versa, and what are the differences? Why is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> always mentioned but never <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>? Thanks for answering my question (if you do)!

Comment: For the same reason you have a bias against  `control-alt-f2`, `f4`, `f5`, and `f6`   ;)

Comment: some info; http://superuser.com/questions/449781/why-is-there-so-many-linux-dev-tty http://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for http://askubuntu.com/questions/385831/use-of-diffrent-terminals http://askubuntu.com/questions/377213/why-so-many-virtual-consoles

Comment: You can log in to multiple consoles (six, by default?) and switch between them with the Ctrl-Alt key combinations.  An early form of multitasking.

Comment: Alt-Ctrl-F1,..., Alt-Ctrl-F6 are multiple consoles. Unix/Linux operating systems are multiuser system from the beginning and in the old days this was a way to enable work for more users. Each user was running her own console with monitor and keyboard connected to a mainframe computer. The same way Alt-Ctrl-F7,..., Alt-Ctrl-F12 are 6 possible consoles for XWindows. If you run more than one XWindows you can switch between them. That is rare as usually users run only one XWindows server. I have had a setup with multiple XWindows servers and was able to switch between them in that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the number there is no difference.

There are some examples where more than 1 tty is useful.

1. `tail -f {logfile}` will show new entries that are added in the logfile. Where you can use another tty to start, stop a service or do some kind of command line instructions, or do something in mysql.
2. same goes for analyzing CPU usages on your system: have `sar` or `top`/`htop` run on 1 tty and then use another session to start a browser, a command or service and by switching tty you can check what happens.

And yes you can do that from a terminal in the desktop but not everyone has a desktop ;)

Comment: But for that we have tmux :)