# Accessing different tty in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, tty

My question is quite simple. I was told that Linux machine launches different tty's, and they can be accessed by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-12</kbd>. I found this:

- <kbd>F2</kbd> brings me to my desktop environment
- <kbd>F3-6</kbd> brings me to what it should - a console proposing me to log in
- <kbd>F7-12</kbd> brings me to the same looking console, but it's empty
- <kbd>F1</kbd> is a weird one. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> from my desktop environment, my monitor stops receiving signal from my PC, and signal returns after switching tty back. When I press the same combination from another tty, I see Ubuntu's login page with all users on my machine (I did not try to login again from there yet, I just return back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

So, why are <kbd>F7-12</kbd> consoles empty and why does <kbd>F1</kbd> behave in such a weird way?

**UPD**: I checked those <kbd>F3-6</kbd> consoles: they work pretty fine.

I also checked <kbd>F7-12</kbd>: they are empty (I only see a blinking pointer) and they don't take any input from keyboard.

And then I discovered that simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is enough to go from <kbd>F3-12</kbd> to that login screen, while inside my desktop environment <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> seems to work pretty much like 'Activities' button in a top-left corner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui) and [Why so many Virtual consoles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377213/why-so-many-virtual-consoles) (for information about how to access tty7-tty12 read Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's answer)

Comment: @karel Well, so are there now only 4 consoles besides a one occupied by desktop environment by default? And before 17.10 there were 6, am I right?

Comment: That's right, but you can open more than the default number of virtual consoles.

Comment: OK then. Many thanks! Now I just want to find out what does the Ctrl+Alt+F1 combination do and why my monitor stops receiving signal.

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 and later, tty1 (accessed by Ctrl+Alt+F1) contains the login screen, and tty2 (accessed by Ctrl+Alt+F2) contains your actual loaded graphical session. The reason why Ctrl+Alt+F1 goes to a black screen is that you were already logged in and you didn't log out before you pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: why people closed this without giving an ubuntu 18 appropriate answer.?