# Root shell on VT 9

Tags: 16.04, root, virtual-console

When I switch to VT 9 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> I get a root shell by default without a password prompt. How can I change it to demand a password before giving root shell access? I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

In [Sergiy's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/817859/502522) he has explained the methods to open VTs with and without `sudo` and includes description of device files of VTs but he has not addressed this problem of mine where I have a default **root shell** on VT9.

Output of `lsof /dev/tty9`

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    281 root    0u   CHR    4,9      0t0   28 /dev/tty9
bash    281 root    1u   CHR    4,9      0t0   28 /dev/tty9
bash    281 root    2u   CHR    4,9      0t0   28 /dev/tty9
bash    281 root  255u   CHR    4,9      0t0   28 /dev/tty9
```

Output of `systemctl status getty@9`

```
● getty@9.service - Getty on 9
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:agetty(8)
           man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
           http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
```

Comment: VT9  should usually show **log messages**, and not able to open an unproctected tty.

Comment: When I try to switch to tty9 by using the command I get the error                              `openvt: vt 9 is in use; command aborted; use openvt -f to force.` . I am wondering now if it's a default thing on Ubuntu or not. It would be great if you or someone else could try it on their machine and see what happens.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo lsof /dev/tty9` and `systemctl status getty@9` to the post, please.

Comment: Now try `pstree -psa 281` (or whichever PID shows up in the `lsof` output) and `systemctl status 281`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a systemd debug shell.

```
debug-shell.service - Early root shell on /dev/tty9 FOR DEBUGGING ONLY
```

It should be disabled by default, and only enabled for debugging. You can disable it with

```
# systemctl disable debug-shell.service
```